# How to style price color on webshop sale price

Tags: javascript, css, angular, webshop

How can I change so the sale price is red and normal prices remain black?
- I tried with div. css - but it doesn't seem like I can only hit the sale price.
See the code below

Product on sale:

```
<div class="prices">
    <s class="is-block m-productlist-price-before-discount" data-ng-bind-html="discount | currency_format">350,00 DKK</s>
    </p>
    <span class="m-productlist-price h5 is-block" data-ng-bind-html="price">250,00 DKK</span>
</div>
```

Product that is not on sale:

```
<div class="prices">
    <span class="m-productlist-price h5 is-block" data-ng-bind-html="price">200,00 DKK</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the opening `<p>` in the first html block?

Comment: Where is the CSS?

Comment: You can use ngClass directive from angular to give a class based on your condition

Comment: Try adding sale / normal to the element's class which you want to color, then find those elements with querySelectorAll, iterate over the array and set the color like this: `element.style.color = "red"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try next element selector using (`+`).

**Please Note:** You have one closing *p* tag which does not have matching opening tag.

```css
.prices p, .prices p+span{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="prices">
  <p>
    <s class="is-block m-productlist-price-before-discount" data-ng-bind-html="discount | currency_format">350,00 DKK</s>
  </p>
  <span class="m-productlist-price h5 is-block" data-ng-bind-html="price">250,00 DKK</span>
</div>

<div class="prices">
  <span class="m-productlist-price h5 is-block" data-ng-bind-html="price">200,00 DKK</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately, does not seem to work - sorry, I've inserted opning tag now

Comment: @Pete, is it not working in your code or in the answer given here?

Comment: can you please have a look, I'm really trying, but I can't make it work under products

Comment: @Pete, The solution is proved based on the structure of the HTML. If the structure does not match the selector will fail and no style will be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Just define a class .red { color: red } and apply it onto your html conditionally, you can do that easily with angular. You could also apply the css conditionally. Read more [here](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/ng-class-angular-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML markup seems to have a lone p closing tag so idk where thats from however you can always use the preceding element tag selector.

```
 s.m-productlist-price-before-discount ~ span.m-productlist-price{
      color:red;
 }
```

Comment: @Pete is the CSS within the right place? or is it coloring the wrong items? I only ask because on my computer i'm seeing the "250,00 DKK"  as red.with the 350,000 crossed out next to it in black.

Comment: sorry, I've inserted opning tag now

Comment: The problem is that both normal price and sale price are colored red - may require Javascript

Comment: @Pete man sorry to hear that! ~ should cause only the span.m-productlist-price element to turn red if its preceded by a s.m-productlist-price-before-discount

Comment: s.m-productlist-price-before-discount - change the pre-price